Forcing Server Reboots if not rebooted within X days of patching (Azure Hosted)
I host numerous RHEL 8 servers in the Azure environment.  I am using a Red Hat Satellite VM to patch servers and then I rely on the owners to reboot once patching is complete.  I want to implement a solution that alerts the POC that they need to reboot and force reboots the server if it has not been rebooted within X number of days since the system was patched.  I am looking to see if anyone else has done this and if they performed this automation on the Azure platform (PowerShell) or if they utilized something like the Ansible Automation Platform (AAP).  If I didn't have to get the POC from Azure and connect it to another system for notification, I would just write a bash script utilizing the patching groups and system uptimes.

"I am looking to see if anyone else has done this", yes. "If they performed this automation on the Azure platform (PowerShell) or if they utilized something like the Ansible Automation Platform (AAP).", both. Does Ansible - How to reboot the server based on condition? answer your question? It is possible to adopt and or enhance based on uptime, which is also available as Ansible fact. And it is working in RHEL 8 and 9 too.

You don't need to use Powershell or Ansible Automation Platform, with the proper configuration of the dnf-automatic package you can create different systemd timers that will notify, download, or install packages and/or security packages.
You can amend it with needs-restarting -r from the yum-utils package.
An Ansible playbook/role might help setting this up with a local_fact that registers and compares the expiration time.

OP: do RTFM for needs-restarting if scripting this - the exit codes are the opposite one would expect from a CLI executable.
